# Flutter dialog box does not close (using rFlutter alert box)

Tags: flutter

I am having an issue using RFlutter (https://github.com/RatelHub/rflutter_alert)  alert in my app..  The dialog box is shown however, the pop command for the dialog removes the underlying page and not the alert box.

Here is my code snippet

This is Home Page

```
class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  HomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);
  final String title;
  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}
class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  int currentIndex = 0;
  final GlobalKey<NavigatorState> firstTabNavKey = GlobalKey<NavigatorState>();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return CupertinoTabScaffold(
      tabBar: CupertinoTabBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.white54,
        items: const <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(CupertinoIcons.search),
            title: Text('search'),
          ),
        ],
        onTap: (index) {
          if (currentIndex == index) {
            switch (index) {
              case 0:
                firstTabNavKey.currentState.popUntil((r) => r.isFirst);
                break;
            }
          }
          currentIndex = index;
        },
      ),
      tabBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
        switch (index) {
          case 0:
            return CupertinoTabView(
              navigatorKey: firstTabNavKey,
              builder: (BuildContext context) => Page1(),
              defaultTitle: 'search',
            );
            break;
        }
        return null;
      },
    );
  }
}
```

This is my page 1 code... The alert box is displayed but when the button "COOL " is pressed.The alert stay on the screen but the bottom page is switching

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:rflutter_alert/rflutter_alert.dart';

    class Page1 extends StatefulWidget {
      Page1();
      @override
      _Page1State createState() => new _Page1State();
    }
    class _Page1State extends State<Page1> {
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
          body: Center(
            child: RaisedButton(
                onPressed: () => Alert(
                      context: context,
                      type: AlertType.error,
                      title: "RFLUTTER ALERT",
                      desc: "Flutter is more awesome with RFlutter Alert.",
                      buttons: [
                        DialogButton(
                            child: Text(
                              "COOL",
                              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 20),
                            ),
                            onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context))
                      ],
                    ).show()),
          ),
        );
      }
    }
```

The full code is here
https://github.com/RatelHub/rflutter_alert/issues/20

Answer (score 4):

I came here to find solution, but no solution here.

Please note that this problem only happened with **CupertinoTabScaffold** and **CupertinoTabBar**.

Later I found solution from the official FlutterGallery source code. This solved my problem and hope it helps you all as well.

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/master/examples/flutter_gallery/lib/demo/cupertino/cupertino_navigation_demo.dart#L122

```
Navigator.of(context, rootNavigator: true).pop();
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm developer of RFlutter Alert plugin. As @Kevin Khew mentioned before correct usage:

```
Navigator.of(context, rootNavigator: true).pop();
```

And fixed this issue with latest version V1.1.0, please upgrade it. If problem continues, I will be ready for further help.

Answer (score -1):

The problem you describe is not included in your code example. Your problem is associated with the `BuildConext`, which you are passing to your `build()` method. I've prepared a minmal example to show your Alert in a minimal working example:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:rflutter_alert/rflutter_alert.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Home()
    );
  }
}

class Home extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: RaisedButton(onPressed: () =>
          Alert(
            context: context,
            type: AlertType.error,
            title: "RFLUTTER ALERT",
            desc: "Flutter is more awesome with RFlutter Alert.",
            buttons: [
              DialogButton(
                child: Text(
                  "COOL",
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 20),
                ),
                onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context)
              )
            ],
          ).show()
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image: dmeo]

Comment: Thanks ..this is same structure I have in my code, The only difference that the the page is coming from a Cupertino tab view.. I will update the show...

Comment: Thanks but it does not work..I updated the code. I see the popup but it does not close the dialog... It pops the underlying page

Comment: sorry for the late reply . No . I just create a container and style it . Then use navigation to pop up the page